# Problem with playa inside url segment conditional

Tags: playa, conditionals

Having an issue placing playa inside a URL segment conditional. Inside the conditional, playa doesn't return entries, though if I substitute the playa call with simple text, the conditional works. And strangely, if I have a blank {if:else} statement, the playa entries will show.

Any ideas?

**Doesn't work:**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my-channel" limit="1"}
   {if segment_3 == "{entry_id}" }

        {exp:playa:children field="my-channel-field"}
            <li><a href="#">{title} - {other-field}</a></li>
        {/exp:playa:children}

   {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**Works:**

```
{if segment_3 == "{entry_id}" }
  Nice id!
 {if:else}
  Sorry, underage!
{/if}
```

**Also works:**

```
   {if segment_3 == "{entry_id}" }
        {exp:playa:children field="my-channel-field"}
            <li><a href="#">{title} - {other-field}</a></li>
        {/exp:playa:children}
    {if:else}
   {/if}
```

Comment: what is difference between first and third code block as both seems same except if:else.

Comment: The last two examples are complex conditionals, while the first one is a simple conditional. The parse order is different, as simple conditionals get parsed *before* modules and plugin tags. See here: http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The difference may be due to the parsing order. The 1st block in your example is a simple conditional, vs the advanced conditional in the 3rd block. So the time the conditional is parsed is [later with the advanced](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html). What if you try adding parse="inward" to your first example:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my-channel" limit="1" parse="inward"}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, probably the parse order. Parse inward unfortunately did not do the trick. Would this be a job for switchee?

Comment: That sounds like the add-on to try!